# Get the specific whole (0) dimension in multidimensional array (C# UNITY)

Tags: c#, android, arrays, unity-game-engine

How can I possibly count only the specific whole column I want in a multidimensional array

I do the counting of my whole column and row like this

```
//COLUMN
for(int col = 0; col < table.GetLength(0); col++)
{
    int sum = 0;
    //ROW
    for (int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(1); row++)
    {
         if (table[col,row] != null)
         {
             sum++;
         }
    }
     Debug.Log("table column: " + col + " has " + sum + " data");
}
```

What I want is just to get the specific whole Column then move to another Column just like that. I need to do this because i need to compare it with the last column value to the next one.

For example : I want to check how many data are there in the 2nd column then compare it with the 1st column.

Comment: From my perspective the code above should work. Do you get any unexpected behaviour? Different results? All you have to do is store the number of rows per column in another list.

Comment: @HimBromBeere yup it is working but only if i want to get the whole column and row . The problem with this code is that it iterates and gets the whole data . What i want is that after iterating the column it will go the next column and now compare if the 1st column has the same length of data to the 2nd column

Comment: When using `GetLength` you assume that your table already *has* equal number of rows per colums (which btw. is the definition of a "table"). Why need to check this again?

Comment: @HimBromBeere it's because of this [rule](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/158969/loop-through-multidimensional-array-in-cunity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution :)

```
//generic function
public static int CountRow<T>(T[,] table, int col)
{
    if (table == null || col < 0 || col >= table.GetLength(1)) 
    {
        //handle error
        return -1;
    }

    //this is the same as the block of the outer for loop
    int sum = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(1); row++)
    {
        if(table[col,row] != null)
        {
            sum++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

then used it like this

```
int prevSum = -1;
for (int col = 0; col < table.GetLength(0); ++col)
{
    int sum = CountRow(table, col);
    Debug.Log("table column :" + col + " has " + sum + " data");
    if (sum == prevSum)
    {
       //comparison happens
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You´re almost there. All you have to do is store the sum of the current column into a list:

```
var List<int> sums = new List<int>();
//COLUMN
for(int col = 0; col < table.GetLength(0); col++)
{
    int sum = 0;
    //ROW
    for (int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(1); row++)
    {
         if (table[col,row] != null)
         {
             sum++;
         }
    }
    Debug.Log("table column: " + col + " has " + sum + " data");
    sums.Add(sum);
}
```

Now you can easily compare the number of rows in colum 1 and that of column 2:

```
bool areEqual = sums[0] == sums[1];
```

Comment: Argument is out of range??

Comment: @TheGinxx009 Then you probably have only a single column. You should start to use your debugger: where do you get the exception? What are the indexes?

Comment: on the sums[0] == sums[1] . I'm still using c# 4.0 so `List<int>sums = new List<int>();` then `if(sums[0] == sums[1])`

Comment: @TheGinxx009 As I already said, this is because `sums` seems to contain either none or only a single value, which can only ocur if you table simply has only a single colum.